# DKIM Signature Body Hash Verified to Office 365

Tags: email, microsoft-office-365, dkim, office365

I am checking the email header in https://mxtoolbox.com and getting the error `DKIM Signature Body Hash Verified`. Problem only occurs when sending emails to other Office 365 accounts. The same email sent to Live and Gmail accounts are fine.

How determine the cause and apply the necessary fix?

Comment: Hi, in your o365 do you have different send connector ? Maybe one bypassing the DKIM signature

Comment: No. It'll be the same connector. I can see there is a hash in the email header for both Gmail and Live accounts.

Comment: Linking from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Office365/comments/16wf3m7/comment/k2wm3wf/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3):


Are the main domain and subdomain on the same Microsoft 365 tenant?
Intra-organizational mail is not signed with DKIM, and email authentication validation is not performed for SPF/DKIM/DMARC.